# SQL state: 42601 syntax error at or near "11"

Tags: postgresql, datetime, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a table `address_all` and it is inherited by several address tables. `address_history` inherits from parent table `history_all` and keeps current address information. I am creating new table which inherits `address_all` table and copies information from `address_history` to new table.

My stored procedure is like this below. I am having some error when I call it. To better explain error I am using line number.

```
1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefunc()
2  RETURNS void AS
3  $BODY$
4  DECLARE
5   year_id INTEGER;
6   month_id INTEGER;
7   week_id INTEGER;
8   addresstablename text; 
9   backupdays text;
10 BEGIN
11  week_id := EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP 'now()');
12  month_id := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP 'now()');
13  year_id := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP 'now()');
14  addresstablename := 'address_history_' || week_id || '_' || month_id || '_' || year_id;
15  backupdays:= date_trunc('hour',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '7 days');
16  EXECUTE 'create table ' || addresstablename || '() INHERITS (address_all)';
17  EXECUTE 'insert into ' || addresstablename || ' select * from address_history where address_timestamp >= ' || backupdays || ''; --AS timestamp without time zone);  
18 END;
19 $BODY$
20 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

When I run:

```
select somefunc()
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "12"
LINE 1: ...story where address_timestamp >= 2012-07-31 12:00:00-0...
                                                         ^
QUERY:  insert into address_history_7_8_2012 select * from address_history where address_timestamp >= 2012-07-31 12:00:00-04
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "somefunc" line 14 at EXECUTE statement

 ********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "12"
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/pgSQL function "somefunc" line 14 at EXECUTE statement
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this largely simplified form:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefunc()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
 addresstablename text := 'address_history_' || to_char(now(), 'FMDD_MM_YYYY');

BEGIN
 EXECUTE 
 'CREATE TABLE ' || addresstablename || '() INHERITS (address_all)';

 EXECUTE
 'INSERT INTO ' || addresstablename || '
  SELECT *
  FROM   address_history
  WHERE  address_timestamp >= $1'
 USING date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '7 days');

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points:

- You can assign variables in plpgsql at declaration time. Simplifies code.
- Use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to format your date. Much simpler.
- `now()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` do the same.
- Don't quote `'now()'`, use `now()` (without quotes) if you want the current timestamp.
- Use the [`USING` clause with `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), so you don't have to convert the `timestamp` to `text` and back - possibly running into **quoting** issues like you did. Faster, simpler, safer.
- In `LANGUAGE plpgsql`, `plpgsql` is a keyword and should not be quoted.
- You may want to check if the table already exists with [`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html), available since PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: Thanks for providing more assist on my query. I am new on postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to quote backupdays, or it is not seen as a string from where to parse a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You're building SQL using string manipulation so you have to properly quote everything just like in any other language. There are a [few functions that you'll want to know about](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

- `quote_ident`: quote an identifier such as a table name.
- `quote_literal`: quote a string to use as a string literal.
- `quote_nullable`: as `quote_literal` but properly handles NULLs as well.

Something like this will server you better:

```
EXECUTE 'create table ' || quote_ident(addresstablename) || ...
EXECUTE 'insert into '  || quote_ident(addresstablename) || ... || quote_literal(backupdays) ...
```

The `quote_ident` calls aren't necessary in your case but they're a good habit.

Comment: `quote_literal()` and `quote_ident()` are good advice, generally. In this case you don't need either, I would claim. The tablename `addresstablename` is generated inside the function and does not take user input, so it can be used as is. The variable `backupdays` can be applied with the `USING` clause, which saves casting and quoting altogether.

Comment: Thanks for sharing about quote_ident, quote_literal and quote_nullable. I will surely use these in my queries. Thanks alot.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Hence the "The `quote_ident` calls aren't necessary in your case but they're a good habit." I would claim that `quote_ident` should be the default thing that your fingers do, then remove it if you're certain you don't need it.

Comment: @muistooshort: I can't disagree with that. Don't get me wrong, I upvoted your answer - it's the deluxe version of the lserni's simple comment.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: No worries, I'm just putting on my "database guy" hat and trying to make sure everything is well defined and free of ambiguity :)