# Syntax error 42601 when trying to run plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to `PL/pgSQL`. While trying to insert data into tables the following function generates an error. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850194/sql-state-42601-syntax-error-at-or-near-11) defines the error, but I can't understand this link problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateScore() 
RETURNS void AS
$$
 DECLARE
 singleTopicCriteriaPercentage DECIMAL(6,6);
 sitePercentage                DECIMAL(6,6);
 singleSiteCriteriaPercentage  DECIMAL(6,6);
 totalSocre                    DECIMAL(6,6);

 cursor1 CURSOR FOR select id from sitereviews order by id;
 cursor2 CURSOR FOR select weight into rating from sitereviews_ratingcriteria where site_id = id;

 id              sitereviews.id%TYPE;
 weights         sitereviews_ratingcriteria.weight%TYPE;

 BEGIN
 singleTopicCriteriaPercentage := (10.0 / 120.0) * 100.0;
 sitePercentage := 0.0;
 singleSiteCriteriaPercentage := 0.0;
 totalSocre := 0.0;

 OPEN cursor1;
 LOOP
 FETCH cursor1 INTO id;
 EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
 totalSocre := 0.0;

OPEN cursor2;
LOOP
FETCH cursor2 INTO weights;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    sitePercentage := singleTopicCriteriaPercentage * weights;
    singleSiteCriteriaPercentage :=  (sitePercentage / 100) * 10;
    totalSocre := singleSiteCriteriaPercentage + totalSocre;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor2;

update sitereviews set weights := round(totalSocre)  WHERE CURRENT OF cursor1;
END LOOP
CLOSE cursor1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'PLPGSQL'
```

following is the compile time error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: update sitereviews set  $1  := round( $2 ) WHERE CURRENT OF ...
                            ^
QUERY:  update sitereviews set  $1  := round( $2 ) WHERE CURRENT OF  $3 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "updatescore" near line 35

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
SQL state: 42601
Context: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "updatescore" near line 35
```

Comment: my column name is `weight` if , replace `weights` with `weight` , there is no action perform.

Comment: It is essential to include the version of PostgreSQL in use. Also, you should have learned not to quote the language name `plpgsql` from the posting you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your update statement to

```
update sitereviews set set weights = round(totalSocre)  WHERE CURRENT OF cursor1
```

or, basically, drop the ":" before the equal sign.  PL/SQL and plpgsql use `:=` for assignment and comparison, but SQL uses `=`.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Did you commit the changes anywhere?  I don't see a COMMIT in the procedure.

Comment: where to put the commit statement ?

Comment: Well, that depends on how this procedure is being used.  If it's part of a larger unit of work you'd have to analyze the code that invokes it and put the COMMIT where it makes sense to have it - i.e. where the unit of work is complete.  If you just need this procedure to do its work and then commit the changes you could try putting a COMMIT at the end of the procedure, after both cursors are closed.

Comment: thanks @bob jarvis . please don't laugh , but how to call the procedure ?

Comment: is it possible to call the procedure in the same sql script file ?

Comment: @BobJarvis: you cannot commit inside a function in Postgres. The transaction handling has to be done by the caller.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how to call the procedure and commit the data ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks.  The limitations of my experience with PostgreSQL is showing.  :-)

Comment: @HarmeetSingh - how have you been invoking the procedure up to this point?

Comment: @BobJarvis sir i am new in plpgsql , so i found some syntax , but i m little bit confused , so i want to confirm .

Comment: Try `SELECT updateScore();`.  What tool are you using to work with your database?  In the past I've used pgAdmin (http://www.pgadmin.org/) when working with PostgreSQL.  It's been a while but if I recall correctly you could open an SQL window, run statements, edit code, **commit transactions**, etc, blah.